# Out of Memory Borland Turbo Debugger MS-DOS 6.22

Tags: debugging, dos

I am trying to debug an MS-DOS 6.22 application using Borland Turbo Debugger 3.1 (Not MS-DOS emulator) but when I try to use **File**  then **Open** menu item to launch EXE I get Out of Memory error. The executable is 269,029 bytes, but it is packed EXE and unpacks to 449,415 bytes. Turbo Debugger (TD.exe) is 491,808 bytes on disk.

[image]

Mem output shows:

[image]

I have the following set in CONFIG.SYS:

[image]

And the following autoexec.bat config:

[image]

Is there any thing I can do to help TD.exe debug this EXE?

Comment: Have you tried `DEVICEHIGH` instead of `DEVICE` for `SETVER.EXE`, and then move it down by two lines? I don't know whether `DEVICEHIGH` could be used for `EMS386.EXE`, it's just far too long ago I last struggled with that. Anyway, in `AUTOEXEC.BAT`, you could temporarily `REM` out `MSCDEX.EXE`, and perhaps even `SMARTDRV.EXE`. And wasn't there a `LOADHIGH` command or something to load executables (like `TD.EXE` in your situation) into the upper memory block?

Comment: I remember, there was a `LH` command that I used in `AUTOEXEC.BAT` for `LH DOSKEY.COM` – maybe this helps you with `TD.EXE`…

Answer (score 1):

TurboDebugger includes several versions:

- TD.exe
- TD286.exe
- TD386.exe

After removing unnecessary device drivers from CONFIG.SYS and still getting an error with LOADHIGH.exe to launch the debugger I found **TD286.exe** (Despite being larger on disk at 548,939 bytes) managed to debug the program successfully with no out of memory error; and still correctly displays CPU as 80486.

Comment: I'd recommend using TD386 if you have at least an '386 CPU, since it can hide itself even better and supports the hardware breakpoints and watchpoints introduced with the '386.

Comment: Ok I noticed hardware breakpoints weren't available which was frustrating. Td386 shows error Cannot Runt TD386; processor is already in V8086, although I'll try to work that out.

Comment: Yah, I forgot about that drawback, it won't work with EMM386 loaded.